# Symfony 3.2 - Loading state till the page fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, loading

Hello everyone,

I'm stuck at some javascript / symfony issue. I got a page that takes more than 10 secondes to load (a lot of forms in it).

The problem is that when the page shows up, it is only the **html** that works and when users start playing with the forms, its not working (cause its stacks ajax requests and return nothing).

[here an example set of ajax reponses for this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP8DF.png)

So I handled a part of it by setting a loading state for each submit.  (I used gasparesganga loading library ).

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $.LoadingOverlay("show");
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
    });
```

Everything works good when the page is fully loaded.

**But** the problem persists between the landing on the page and the time it fully load. 
I tried to display a spinner when the user get on the page :

```
$.LoadingOverlay("show");
window.onload = function() {
        console.log('window loaded');
        $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
    };
```

**Or** try to replace the  at the beginning of my code:

```
<script>
    $("body").LoadingOverlay("show");
</script>
```

But none of this works; thus when I land on the page, I see first the HTML for 8 seconds and then it shows the spinner.

So my question concerns the fact that Symfony have a role in this : the controller do his calculations and it displays the view as it is till it gets the full informations -- and next load the JS.
If someone could give me some hint, it would be great !

Thanks for the reading and for your help.

Youyou

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found how to get it.
If the controller is taking too much time to respond : 
You can put a loading screen (onclick() ) on every link heading to the heavy page. 
No need to hide it with .hide(), it will redirect anyways...
And in the heavy page you put a script in your header before the body the **same loading screen you made before**:

```
document.write('<div class = "loader centered" style="...">');
```

This will start a loading screen as soon as you land on the page. 
So when the page fully loads you can remove the loading state at the bottom of your view code :

```
$(function() { //equals window.onload or ready
$('.loader').hide();
// ... retrieve opacity, pointer-events etc...
```

Now there is only a small refresh due to PHP (no way to dodge it -go full njs-), but it gives you more control on the user actions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a loader that not depends on Jquery library, the loader does not appear because Jquery is not loaded yet. maybe you need to search an js full loader. Good Luck !

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I made sure Jquery was loaded, otherwise I would get a $ undefined error in the console, which didn't occur... Solved with scripts in head to avoid loading the body content

Comment: Thanks for share your solution !